# How do I change the django-registration e-mail template "site" name?

Tags: python, django

The current setup ends up substituting example.com into the below code from the template. I want it to point to localhost:8000

Without hard coding this, where and how can I change the template so that the site is linked to my localhost?

Thank you for registering an account at {{ site.domain }}.
To activate your registration, please visit the following page:

http://{{ site.domain }}{% url registration_activate activation_key %}

This page will expire in {{ expiration_days }} day{{ expiration_days|pluralize }}.

---

If you didn't register this account you can simply delete this email and we won't bother you again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `site` object in the template comes from the Django Site model. When you do a `syncdb`, it defaults automatically to `example.com`

If you login to Django's admin interface, you will find "Sites". Inside it, you will be able to change `example.com` to whatever you like.

[image]